# How to set constructor based injection values

Tags: spring, javabeans

```
<bean id="someBean" class="someClass" >
        <constructor-arg index="0"  value=""/>       
        <constructor-arg index="1"  value=""/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

How can I set values from java code?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the constructor arguments to getBean method as below. But this will work only if the scope of your bean is configured as prototype.

```
 context.getBean("someBean" , new Object[] {"kswaughs", "Stackoverflow user"} );
```

If you try to call this method for singleton beans, Spring will throw below error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Can only specify arguments for the getBean method when referring to a prototype bean definition